# AngularJS Typeahead error on returning results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I have the following code that makes use of AngularJS and the Angular Bootstrap Typeahead widget. The problem is that it only returns an error- property length of 'undefined'. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
 <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
  <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Patients loaded via $http" typeahead="result.patient.drug.drugindication for result in getPatient($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingPatients" class="form-control">
 <i ng-show="loadingPatients" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.getPatient = function(val) {
return $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
  params: {
    search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
  }
}).then(function(response){
    //the following console log returns the data just fine
    console.log(response.data.results)
  return 
  { 
    result: response.data.result
  }
});
};
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

That means response from your server not contain requested data, if you type into browser address

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?patient.drug.drugindication=a

you can see only error message

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check this link out https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.drugindication:ASPIRIN

then you must change your code to this so you just need to return Promise and you don't need to use then() so change your code to

```
     $scope.getPatient = function(val) {
      return $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
       params: {
           search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
        }
      })
     };
```

if you want to use then() follow this code which means return data

```
$scope.getPatient = function(val) {
var data = $http.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json', {
  params: {
    search: 'patient.drug.drugindication:' + val
  }
});
data.then(function(response){
   console.log(response.data.results)
});
  return data;
};
```

and if you want more follow the pattern below

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=seriousnesslifethreatening:1+AND+patient.drug.medicinalproduct:%22ASPIRIN%22+AND+patient.patientsex:1&limit=10
```